# Count the number occurrence in List<Integer>

Tags: java, list, count

I'm creating a small application that calculates a grade for a student. It takes two `List<Integer>` within a method.

If my `list` contains 8 items, for example; `{52,62,65,65,72,72,75,75}` I want to find a way of counting through that `list` and finding the items that are within the same tenth (eg; 30, 40, 50, 60, 70). So this in case, 4 items will be within 70's and then be able to store it (known as a upper boundary). The aim of this is so that if 4 items are in a upper boundary, the overall student grade will be greater.

My question is, how could I achieve this? I have seen that I could use some sort of `map` but I'm not sure if that will be the best way of achieve it.

Comment: You could just sort and count.

Answer (score 2):

> Iterate over your list and put entries into Map
>   where key is a number and value is a count.

Expanding on this previous answer a with a little psuedocode...

```
Map<Integer, Integer> gradeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int roundedGrade = (grade / 10) * 10;
// Where "incrementMap" is a function you define...
// The purpose of the method is to increment the value (counter) in the map for a particular key
// If the key doesn't exist yet, you want to add it with an initial count of "1"
// Jérémy Dutheil's answer is a good example of this method, but I can include the actual ones that I use since it is a generic library method (see below)
incrementMap(gradeMap, roundedGrade);

// To find upper boundary
int upperBoundary = 0;
for(Map.entry<Integer,Integer> entry : gradeMaps.getEntries())
{
  int count = entry.getValue();
  int tenth = entry.getKey();
  // determine if this is the upper boundary
}
```

Here is an example implementation for incrementMap:

```
public static <T> void incrementMap(Map<T, Integer> map, T key)
{
    incrementMap(map, key, 1);
}

public static <T> void incrementMap(Map<T, Integer> map, T key, int amountToIncrement)
{
    assert map != null;
    int currentValue = map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) : 0;
    map.put(key, currentValue + amountToIncrement);
}
```

I may be pulling us onto a tangent... the only reason I included the generics was because I wanted to give you actual code that I find useful in my library, rather than only psuedo-code. If you want to make this simpler to understand, replace every occurence of "T" with "Integer". The purpose of the  is to allow you to use this same method for a Map with any type of "key", as long as the "values" are of type Integer. It doesn't have to be "T" specifically, that's just the example you will get from most tutorials. (for example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html)

For example, check out this utility method that uses two different generic types:

```
/**
 * Convenience method to create a map containing a single entry.
 * @param pKey the entry key
 * @param pValue the entry value
 * @param <K> the key type
 * @param <V> the value type
 * @return a map with a single entry
 */
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOfOne(K pKey, V pValue)
{
    Map<K, V> target = new HashMap<K, V>();
    target.put(pKey, pValue);
    return target;
}
```

Comment: You mention that `incrementMap` is a function, can you expand on that please?

Comment: Just for my reference, how does the <T> part work? I know it is used to allow for dynamic typing of the function, but can be confusing when trying to understand the functions purpose. Also does it have to be a T or can it be any letter? Can there be more than one dynamic type?

Comment: Thank you for covering my question(though a comment would have sufficed). It is a shame I cant give you another +1 for the extra work.

Comment: You're right Dan, that should have been a comment. At first I thought it was a follow-up question by the OP, but I later realized it was not. Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your list and put entries into `Map<Integer, Integer>` where key is a number and value is a count.

Comment: I have never used `Map` before. Would it be possible for you to give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that in fact, no one who answered never really understood your question ; it is not just about counting an occurence, but finding the occurence tenth' and then counting the number for each tenth.

So first, we need a function that will determine the tenth for a given integer

```
int getTenth( int number ) {
    return Math.floor( number / 10 );
}
```

Here we simply divide number by 10 (as you give only number < 100 in your example), and we round it as the lower integer nearest.

Then you will have to store the count for each of tenth that are in your lists ; for that, we'll use a `Map` that allow you to store a list of **keys** with associated **values** (please see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for more information. In your problem, we will use the tenth as keys, and the count as values.

```
function Map< Integer, Integer > getTenthCount( List< Integer > list ) {
    Map< Integer, Integer> tenthCount = new HashMap< Integer, Integer >();

    for( Integer i : list ) {
        int tenth = getTenth( i );
        if( !tenthCount.containsKey( tenth ) ) {
            tenthCount.put( tenth, 1 );
        } else {
            // Value exists, add to count
            int count = tenthCount.get( tenth );
            count++;
            tenthCount.put( tenth, count );
        }
    }

    return tenthCount;
}
```

Then you can easily use those two functions for parsing values from your list and use it.

Comment: It loops through your list. The if statement checks if the current list item<integer> is in the list(!results.containsKey( i )). If the item<integer> is not found in the map, it is added to the map. If the item exists, get the count and increment it by the items value.

Comment: I made an edit 'cause the question was misunderstood, now I answer correctly and with explanations, let's have a look ;)